# Fractions in equations along with normal variables

Tags: fractions

I have an equation to be written in latex with fraction and hat variable as follows

[image]

For this, I have used the following code with package \usepackage{mathtools}.

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq2}
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}\textsubscript{t} \bigg[\frac{$\pi${\textsubscript{\theta}}
(a\textsubscript{t}\,|\,s\textsubscript{t})}
{$\pi${\textsubscript{\theta}\textsubscript{old}}
(a\textsubscript{t}\,|\,s\textsubscript{t})}\bigg]\^{A}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Even though I have used \frac{}{} and \^{} in latex, I am still unable to get the output as stated in the equation. The output which I have got using this code is

[image]

Strangely I cannot even see the denominator part and also the hat variable. Could someone please help me if I have done some mistake or any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: That is because it is compiling *with errors*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `\textsubscript` in math mode.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq2}
\hat{\mathbb{E}}_t \biggl[\frac{\pi_{\theta}
(a_t\,|\,s_t)}
{\pi_{\theta_{\mathrm{old}}}
(a_t\,|\,s_t)} \hat A_t\biggr]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also consider using `\mid` in lieu of `\,|\,`, depending on your spacing preference.

Comment: Thanks a million ton.. This helps me a lot :)